# ArCore: How to restrict PlaneFindingMode to only vertical surfaces?

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

I am new to ARCORE and Kotlin and trying a simple android-kotlin app that need to detect walls. I know Google's made it possible with PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL tag,  but I am not sure how to use it.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588885/how-to-disable-surface-detection-in-arcore-android) but I'll answer it anyway.

This implementation is probably applicable to ARCore as well. But I tested this with SceneForm SDK

Setup the AR Session first and use an extension function to modify plane finding.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    //Check if ARSession is null. If it is, instantiate it
    if(arSession == null) {
        arSession = Session(this@EdgeActivity)
        arSession?.setupPlaneFinding()
    }
}


// Setup plane detection
private fun Session.setupPlaneFinding() {

    //Create the config
    arConfig = Config(this)

    //Pause the session | Not sure if this is required for modifying plane detection. I was using this for something else, try & modify at your end
    pause()

    // Modify the plane finding mode
    arConfig?.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL

    //Reinstate the session
    resume()

    //Sceneform requires that the ARCore session is configured to the UpdateMode LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE. | I kept getting an exception if I remove this line. Again, this method is part of a bigger code, this particular line may not be required at your end. Try & Modify
    arConfig?.updateMode = Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE

    //Reconfigure the session
    configure(arConfig)

    //Setup the session with ARSceneView | Very important
    fragment.arSceneView.setupSession(this)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have one minor doubt, what will be the value of arSession if if condition? how did you initialize the session. Mine is happening through the fragment. so, should I assign arSession = fragment.arSceneview.session?

Comment: If you're using it in the fragment, that means you're using SceneForm.

In that case, you have to create a new AR session using `arSession = Session(this@EdgeActivity)` and assign it to your `SceneView` using `fragment.arSceneView.setupSession(this@Session)`.

Did you try debugging `arSession = fragment.arSceneview.session`? It ought to respond with NULL. Even if it doesn't, any modifications will not be applied to the sceneview.

Comment: I tried debugging, yes it responded with Null.

this is the fragment:
 `<fragment
        android:id="@+id/ar_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.myArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`
and according to https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/ it automatically creates a session?

Comment: I don't understand how it works on a very low level. Better raise a bug on GitHub if you want more information on that particular piece. Please consider marking this as the answer if your primary query is resolved.

Comment: @Dev Hi Dev. Please consider marking the response as an accepted answer if it worked for you. If not, please clarify further why not.

Comment: this solution works for me but session is always null in if condition so it always creates a new one.