# sceneView.getSession() returns null

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I have sceneform sample hellosceneform app with its arFragment and want to add object on custom coordinates. For this, as I understood, I need to have a session to add an Anchor on it then create a Node etc. But when I run `arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession()` to call `createAnchor()` on it, I get `null`. How to get **not null** session?

P.S.  arFragment is standard hellosceneform's ux fragment:
`arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment)`

Comment: Possibly links to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427301/arcore-how-to-restrict-planefindingmode-to-only-vertical-surfaces/52440721#comment91828412_52440721). The question has nothing to do with your scneario, but read the comments.